# What is security property 'Server user identity' used for in Websphere Application Server?

Tags: websphere

When configuring the global security for Websphere Application Server, no matter you choose Federated Repositories, LDAP registry or custom registry, there is a property named 'Server user identity' to be setup. According to the official explanation, this is used for authentication during server to server communication. Does it mean when server communicating with each other within one cell, authentication is required and this value would be used there? And does this value only impact internal process, like within same cell? Or it can also be between cells? If it's not leveraged like this way, then how does 'Server user identity' work?

Kinda don't understand this. Please help me figure it out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until WAS 6, a single user identity was required, namely 'primary administrative user', for both administrative access and internal process communication . This user, by definition, had to exist on the configured user registry.

From version 6.1 onwards, WAS requires an administrative user, distinguished from the server user identity, so that administrative actions can be audited separately.

For all practical purposes, if you are using version 6.1+, and you are not in a mixed-release cell (cell containing profiles of older versions of WAS in addition to current versions), you may just go ahead with automatically generated internal user id. An internally-generated server ID also adds a further level of protection to the server environment because the server password is not exposed.

For mixed-release cells you may check [infocenter here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftsec_interoperaten.html) for details on how to configure server user id in this case.

Server user id is used for server to server communication in a cell. I could not find any documentation that implies this parameter is also related with cross cell communication.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  'primary administrative user' is for WAS administration while server user id for interprocess communication within only one cell rather than cross cell.  It's clear, thanks.

Comment: You're wellcome. You may also consider [accepting this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you think it's helpful.