# Lost access to websphere admin console

Tags: webserver, websphere, admin

I'm kind of new with websphere. I was following an internal guide for setting up one of our company apps in websphere, but I changed one parameter in the admin console and after restarting the server, we cannot access with the administration console.[image]

I checked the first option, when before the second one was, with user admin, and password admin also. Now, because It says "Server identity generated automatically" I have no idea what combination of user and password I need to enter in the administration console..

- The administration console I'm referring to is the one located in server:port/ibm/console.
  Thanks, this is really a serious problem for me, I would really appreciate any help I can get...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should still be able to use whatever password you were using for admin user before making the change. Server user id is not used for restricting access to administrative console (see [What is security property 'Server user identity' used for in Websphere Application Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526875/what-is-security-property-server-user-identity-used-for-in-websphere-applicati)).

Nonetheless, since you can't access admin console at the moment (I'm assuming you mean that admin colsole login page shows up but you can't get admin user authenticated due to wrong password), first thing I'd suggest is turning of global security, so that you can use admin console to fix your settings and re-enable security. Once security is turned off, you won't be asked for a password during admin console login. [Changing security settings in WebSphere Application Server with wsadmin](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21173912) technote gives step by step instructions.

If you are not sure about what password you have used for admin user, you must reset the password in the user repository you have configured (for example if you've configured LDAP, you must reset password at LDAP), before enabling security. If you are using a federated repository (this is default if you've not changed it), most probably admin user resides in file based repository, which is the first member of federated repository. In this case, you can just follow steps at [How to reset the administrator's password in the file registry](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21392427) technote to reset your password. Otherwise you can try alternative documented at [Updating your WAS administrator password](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/sametime/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.sametime.advanced.doc/stv_adm_t_adm_pw.html) (the link is from Lotus documentation but still is applicable).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up switching off global security, and reanabled the option that I had changed. Everything works now!

Comment: Too bad that the two links in the end are broken. Better to summarize what is in links to provide future readers a solution/idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Given that** you have the command line '**xmlstarlet**' in your terminal and,

- WAS_HOME = Is your Websphere root location
- PROFILENAME = IS your
  profile's name
- CELLNAME = Is your cell's name

**Then**,

```
xmlstarlet edit --update "/security:Security[@enabled='true']/@enabled" --value "false" $WAS_HOME/profiles/$PROFILENAME/config/cells/$CELLNAME/security.xml > /tmp/security.xml
cp /tmp/security.xml $WAS_HOME/profiles/$PROFILENAME/config/cells/$CELLNAME/security.xml
```

**Summary**: You are simply editing the correct **security.xml** file by changing the **enabled="true"** attribute to **enabled="false"** programmatically using *xmlstarlet*. Note that sed,awk,ed and other GNU tools lack the necessary ability to properly deal with the nested tree structure of XML.